# Call url with ajax in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a while loop in php like this:

```
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['user_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['username']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['reg_phone']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['provider_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['trans_id'] ?></td>
    <td><input type='button' class='<?php echo $row['trans_id']?>' id="yes" value ='Yes' ></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

and here is javascript code:

```
<script>
    $('#yes').click(function() {
        var trans_id=$(this).attr("class");
    $.ajax({

      url: 'infomation/gc_details_2.php',
      data: {'id':trans_id},
      success: function(result) {
         $('#result').html(result);
       }
    });
  });
    </script>
```

When I click on button `Yes`, it request to `gc_details_2` and result is showing `trans_id` of row I clicked. But it does not show like that. It showing `trans_id` of first row. And when I click on button of other row it does not work, and does not showing anything. Am I doing something wrong? Help me

Comment: You cannot have multiple input tags with same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML, an `id` is a unique identifier. That means you can only use it once on a page.

Because only one can exist, when you're attaching the `click` handler, the `this` portion of the click handler is referencing the first element found with the unique identifier.

Change the `id` to a `class` if you want to use it multiple times on the same page.

`<td><input type='button' class='yes <?php echo $row['trans_id']?>' value ='Yes' ></td>`

and

`$('.yes').click(function() {...}`